# ReactJs Component is rendered before cordovas onDeviceReady function

Tags: javascript, cordova, reactjs

I'm currently experimenting with React JS (v.0.14) and cordova.
I want to read some files from the sdcard of an Android Emulator with the cordova file plugin.

When I try to start the app, I always got the error, that `cordova.file.*` is undefined. This happens because, the React Components are rendered before the cordova `onDeviceReady` is called. I added the `ReactDOM.render` function inside of the `onDeviceReady` function, but that don't work.

app.js

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        console.log('on ready');    // Update DOM on a Received Event

        ReactDOM.render(
          <App />,
          document.getElementById('app')
        );
    }
};
app.initialize();

var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {tiles:[]};
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        var PATH = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 'testdir/'; //Is called before onDeviceReady

    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navigation title="Dashboard"/>
                <Dashboard tiles={this.state.tiles}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

index.html:

```
<body>
        <!-- fixed top navbar -->
        <div id="app">

        </div>
        <!-- Dashboard -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/react/react.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/react/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/browser.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/babel" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
```

The error message from the console are:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'externalRootDirectory' of undefined ...
on ready
```

How can I load my React Components after or in `onDeviceReady`?

Thanks & Greets,
mybecks

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i was waiting for the device information.

Take a look at this link [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/390/how-to-know-if-your-application-is-running-in-cordova-or-a-web-browser) too.

Following this link, i came up with this code:

```
function initApp () {
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
};

if (window.cordova) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", () => {
        initApp();
    }, false);
} else {
    initApp();
}
```